# Is it possible for SQL Server to return different aliased column names from a UNION query using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, union

I have several `SELECT` queries in a `UNION` statement (or `UNION ALL`).  As it is a `UNION` it is going to return the single dataset with one column (I only have one value return in this case), typically the column name from the first query.

I aliased the columns in each query, so I can use the data by name instead of index in my PHP script.

Is it possible to get the individual column names aliased from each individual `SELECT`?

Consider,

```
SELECT name as manager FROM employees WHERE type = 1
UNION
SELECT name as mid_level_manager FROM employees WHERE type = 2
UNION
SELECT name as regular_employee FROM employees WHERE type = 3
```

I am using PDO with Prepared Statements, like this,

```
$results = $prepared_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Maybe not the best example, but how could I get those aliased column names?  Query works fine in and of itself.  I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The result set from your union query will have a single column. That column will get its name from the first query in the UNION. Since you only have one column, you can only name one column. If you would like to have more columns, then you will have to adjust your query to reflect that.

Comment: @JNevill I was hoping there was a way that I did not know about to overcome the native functionality.  I guess that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Agree with @JNevill - I don't really understand why you'd want to do what you're asking. Why not just run 3 separate queries - you're doing that anyway, using UNION.

Comment: Your query effectively does `SELECT DISTINCT name AS manager FROM employees WHERE type IN (1,2,3)`.  I suspect you want something else than a UNION query.  What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only a single name for a single column, but you might add the `type` column indicating which select returned that row:

```
SELECT type, name as manager FROM employees WHERE type = 1
UNION
SELECT type, name as mid_level_manager FROM employees WHERE type = 2
UNION
SELECT type, name as regular_employee FROM employees WHERE type = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  A UNION is going to use the aliased column name from the first query (I think, it might be the last).  That's the point of a UNION.

You can select multiple columns and alias each one, but you can't have a different column alias for different *rows*, that does not make sense.